# Define a binary operation on the set of even integers which is different from addition,substraction and multiplication

Tags: binary-operations

> Question: Define a binary operation on the set of even integers which is different from addition,substraction and multiplication.

My attempt: $a \circ b = a + b - ab$ where $a\in G$ and $b\in G$ ($G$ is the set of all even numbers)

Is my answer is correct,i have mixed the addition, multiplication. 
Or $a \circ b = \max \left\{ a, b\right\}$ where $a\in G$ and $b\in G$ ($G$ is the set of all even numbers) .or this is correct?

Comment: (It's *subtraction*, not substraction.)

Comment: Your example is correct, but there are far simpler examples. Define $a\circ b=42$ for all even integers $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both of them are correct since, in each case, if $a$ and $b$ are even integers, then $a\circ b$ is an even integer too.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit more elaborated. Let the set $G$ be the set of all nubers divisible by $k$, so $$G=\{...-2k,-k,0,k,2k,3k,...\}$$ then $G$ is closed under operation you defined.

Take $a,b\in G$, then exist $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that $a=kx$ and $b=ky$. Now we have:

$$ a\circ b = kx+ky-kx\cdot ky = k(\underbrace{x+y-kxy}_{z\in \mathbb{Z}}) = kz$$ so $ a\circ b \in G$.

You where asking about the special case when $k=2$.